# Recipe for resolving a coherent sheaf

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, vector-bundles, sheaf-theory, complex-manifolds

Let $X$ be a complex manifold and let $V\subset X$ be a subvariety. Let $F\rightarrow V$ be a holomorphic vector bundle over $V$ and let $\mathcal{S}=\Gamma(F)$ be the sheaf of holomorphic section of $F$. As $\mathcal{S}$ is coherent over $X$ it admits a resolution by holomorphic vector bundles $E^i$ over $X$.

Is there a canonical recipe for building these vector bundles $E^i$?

Comment: What do you mean by "canonical"?

Comment: @WillSawin I actually mean just a recipe with the fewest choices.

Comment: Don’t you need an extra condition on $X$ in there like ‘algebraic’?

Comment: If $X$ is projective, one can use coproduces of twisted invertible sheaves $\mathcal{O}(n)$ but probably you already know this.

Comment: Let me summarize the above comments, with some additional remarks: 1) If $X$ is just a complex manifold, then a resolution by bundles on $X$ need *not* exist 2) If $X$ is projective with fixed very ample bundle, and you know the Castelnuovo-Mumford regularity of $V$, then you can give a canonical resolution. But I don't see how you would do it without additional information.

Comment: @DonuArapura When X is projective with fixed very ample bundle. do you have a reference where it describes that "canonical" resolution?

Comment: if I understand the comment correctly, then you can read about the *global syzygy* associated to a coherent sheaf in e.g. Chapter 5, Section 4 ("Global Duality") of Griffiths and Harris' _Principles of Algebraic Geometry_. Either way, I believe the result about resolutions given the existence of a very ample bundle are found somewhere in this book.